# What are .pkg files in flash drive?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, tftp, backups

I have a Cisco 3650 switch and want to backup my IOS via tftp.

System image file is `flash:packages.conf`

```
#sh flash   
cat3k_caa-base.SPA.03.03.05SE.pkg   
cat3k_caa-drivers.SPA.03.03.05SE.pkg  
cat3k_caa-infra.SPA.03.03.05SE.pkg  
cat3k_caa-iosd-universalk9.SPA.150-1.EZ5.pkg   
cat3k_caa-platform.SPA.03.03.05SE.pkg  
cat3k_caa-wcm.SPA.10.1.150.0.pkg       
packages.conf   
nvram_config  
vlan.dat
```

Which file i want to download for backup the current ios on cisco switch?

And how can i download this ios to another switch?

Comment: As already mentioned in an answer, most probably this switch is not a 3560. Please confirm the switch model with the command `show inventory`

Comment: Its 3650 switch, how to download those files to switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible you are talking about 3650, not 3560? The switch is running in "install mode" and .pkg files are packages extracted from .bin. You could check the files that switch is using with a command:

show version running

Backup all these files + packages.conf (if you do not have original *.bin file)

Comment: Yes, its my mistake, the switch is 3650. i took all .pkg files. how to download to another same switch? Its the same way like dealing with .bin?